# Add a pause between loops of an animation

Tags: css

I've got this animation that I want to add a pause in between its loops / iterations. I've tried doing it with `animation-delay` but that of course only applies for the first iteration. Now I've set the animation to take up 3s to make it a bit slower and not spam as much but It would be neat with a pause in between. Any ideas on how to best achieve this?

This is the code:

```
.--bounce {
        -moz-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
        animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes bounce {
        0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }

        40% {
            transform: translateY(-30px);
        }

        60% {
            transform: translateY(-15px);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make pause a part of your animation - in the snippet below the *actual* animation takes 50% of `bounce`, the rest is *pause*.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lime;
}

.--bounce {
  -moz-animation: bounce 6s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 6s infinite;
  animation: bounce 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  10%,
  25%,
  40%,
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  20% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  30% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box --bounce"></div>
```

Comment: When I apply that code to mine it does one iteration then the ".box" moves right instead for some seconds and pops back up.

Comment: It's impossible to tell why that happens without [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)